# Email verification of otrs system at localhost?

Tags: otrs

I have tried to create a user - admin at OTRS system (localhost) installed this way ["Nice tutorial. Thanks!"](http://houseofmac.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/how-to-install-otrs-help-desk-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/). 
But I met the DNS problem, while the email was verified. 
How do I solve it?

To solve this issue I went to

> /opt/otrs/Kernel/System

There you can find the file CheckItem.pm
implement:

> sudo nano CheckItem.pm

There I have modified the CheckEmail subroutine:

```
sub CheckEmail {
    return 1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you either can't resolve domains OR the email address you try to type in does not have a valid MX record on the DNS server your OTRS system uses.

You can change the DNS server by setting `CheckMXRecord::Nameserver` under `Admin > SysConfig > Framework > Core` to a valid nameserver.

Alternatively you can set `CheckMXRecord` to 'No' under `Admin > SysConfig > Framework > Core` if you do not want DNS lookup validation at all.